# How would I use an asynchronous function as a default parameter for another function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

I am trying to make a function that will call another function if the parameter doesn't exist.

For example:

```
function getAllFoo(){
    // makes a request to an api and returns an array of all foos
}

function getNumFoo(foosArray = getAllFoo(), num = 5){
    // selects num of foos from foosArray or calls getAllFoos then selects num of them
}
```

Comment: Why not just split it into multiple functions?

Comment: No real reason beyond just wanting to see if there was a way to make this work. Splitting it into two functions would be more clear, as well as solve the issue, but I wanted to learn something new.

Comment: I don't think this really fits well with default parameters. You would have to do it the old fashioned way with [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap your asynchronous function with JS Promise, and in your dependent function call its `then()` function:

```
function getAllFoo () {
  return new Promise(
    // The resolver function is called with the ability to resolve or
    // reject the promise
    function(resolve, reject) {
      // resolve or reject here, according to your logic
      var foosArray = ['your', 'array'];
      resolve(foosArray);
    }
  )
};

function getNumFoo(num = 5){
  getAllFoo().then(function (foosArray) {
    // selects num of foos from foosArray or calls getAllFoos then selects num of them
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllFoo(){
    // makes a request to an api and returns an array of all foos
}

function getNumFoo(foosArray = getAllFoo(), num = 5){
    // Call getAllFoo() when num is not passed to this function
    if (undefined === num) {
        getAllFoo();
    }
}
```

Comment: A sorry did not get what you are trying to do at first ... Why not just use a promise ?

Comment: I agree; not my question.

Answer (score 0):

You would wrap the async function in a promise.

```
    function promiseGetNumFoo(num) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        // If there's an error, reject; otherwise resolve
        if(err) {
          num = 5;
        } else {
          num = resolve(result);
      ).then((num) =>
        // your code here
    )}
```